# Restarting a service and check for status on a remote server via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, service, scripting, powershell-remoting

I'm new to PowerShell. I want to create a script that will Stop a running service then start it back up and display the status of the service but having trouble combining them. Currently, I was able to use Get service to start and stop the service and as well as checking the status of it individually. Is there any way to combine them into one script. Ideally, a script that will check if the service is on or off and do an if/else function. (such as if the service is off, have it stay off and if its on turn if off etc)

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\Servers.txt
$services = Get-COntent -Path "C:\Scripts\Services.txt   

foreach($server in $servers){
    foreach($service in $services){
        (Get-Service -computername $Servers -name $service).Stop()
        (Get-Service -computername $Servers -name $service).Start()    
         Write-Host (Get-Service -ComputerName S$Servers -Name $service).Status
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should format your code example (include the first two statements)

Comment: The {scriptblock} is missing with your `ForEach` see `Get-Help about_foreach` or visit [about_foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Also, for restarting a service, you should first try to `Stop()` and next do the `Start()`

Comment: Each ForEach needs a {scriptblck}, stack them. And your variable iterating the servers is the singular server.

Comment: @LotPings 
{  Stop-Service $Server.Service -ComputerName $Server.ComputerName
}
Like this?

Comment: @LotPings Should I take off the "foreach($server in $servers)" since i only need the script to put out the server name from the server.txt?

Answer (score 1):

- It's your choice to either use the `.stop()` method or
- pipe the service to the `Start-Service` cmdlet.

Untested

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\Servers.txt"
$services = Get-COntent -Path "C:\Scripts\Services.txt"   

foreach($server in $servers){
    foreach($service in $services){
        (Get-Service -computername $Server -name $service).Stop()
        (Get-Service -computername $Server -name $service).Start()    
         Write-Host (Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $service).Status
    } 
}
```

---

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\Servers.txt"
$services = Get-COntent -Path "C:\Scripts\Services.txt"   

foreach($server in $servers){
    foreach($service in $services){
        Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $service | Stop-Service
        Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $service | Start-Service    
         Write-Host (Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $service).Status
    } 
}
```

Comment: I got an error stating " A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:Scripts\Services\Services.txt'. at line1 char 23.   
+ Category info   : InvalidArguement (:) [Get-Content], ParemeterBidning Exception 
+FullyQualifiedErrorID : PositionParemeterNotFound.Mircosoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand.

Not sure what is causing it.

Comment: Somehow the ending double quotes got lost, changed.